# GNU nano 2: DOS Format or Mac Format on Linux

Tags: linux, macintosh, nano, file-format

Which format (Mac or DOS) should I use on Linux PCs/Clusters?

[I know the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617814/difference-between-dos-format-and-mac-format):

- DOS format uses "carriage return" (CR or `\r`) then "line feed" (LF or `\n`).
- Mac format uses "carriage return" (CR or `\r`)
- Unix uses "line feed" (LF or `\n`)

I also know [how to select the option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368223/nano-2-0-6-saving-a-file-in-mac-format):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> for Mac format
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for DOS format

But there is no UNIX format.

Then save the file with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use neither: enter a filename and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the file will be saved with the default Unix line-endings (which is what you want on Linux).

If `nano` tells you it’s going to use DOS or Mac format (which happens if it loaded a file in DOS or Mac format), *i.e.* you see

```
File Name to Write [DOS Format]:
```

or

```
File Name to Write [Mac Format]:
```

press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> respectively to deselect DOS or Mac format, which effectively selects the default Unix format.

Answer (score 4):

`Unix, Linux, new macOS   \n
 DOS, Windows             \r\n
 old Mac OS               \r`

Save in DOS Format, then cd to the folder where you have the file and perform:

`cp -i ./<file> /home/petr/Documents/whatIfBackups/<file>`
to back it up and then re-format from the dos to unix line endings:

`sudo dos2unix <file>`

(`file <file>` shows the status of line endings. "ASCII text" stands for Unix/Linux/new macOS. Alternatively you could also save in Mac Format and then re format by `sudo mac2unix <file>.`)